# Is there any way to select string from disabled HTML select tag element?

Tags: html, select

[image]HTML select tag has disabled attribute and it makes Element as disabled. I just wanted to call it as readonly mode because it is needed on my project.
Problem is user can not select string from disabled select element.

User should be able to select string and copy it but it is impossible for now.
Cursor was shaped as blocked so I changed it using css and tried again.

But it didn't help.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_disabled

Please try on this TryItEditor of W3school and select string "Volvo" using mouse. Impossible.

Is there any other way to solve this problem simply?

Comment: If you don't want the user to change the value (the form element is disabled) then why use a form element in the first place?  Why not just display it as text for the user?

Comment: There is button named "edit" and it makes select option as normal. Then user select only thing from its dropdown list and click save button. it makes select option as readonly again. This is the workflow of my project.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do here then.  Even when enabled, one can't highlight the text in an `<option>` element to copy it.  Maybe have a separate element which displays the currently selected option for the purpose of user highlighting?

Comment: I added screenshot of page. As you can see when user visit this page then he will see disabled select option. And let's suppose he is trying to copy string "AWS" from select element so he tried to drag mouse on this element. but it is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

So if you need an element in  html to be in readonly mode you can do it simply like this.

```
<div>  Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="John Doe" readonly><br> </div>
```

You can copy the string(text) inside the input but not change.. At least this is what i think you asked for.. Hope helped you

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DopeAt/gsczqaj1/)